# hearthbeat can't run

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, heartbeat

I have ELK server, and sending Heartbeats to server. I added an monitor in monitors.d directory, added `setup.dashboards.enabled: true` line in heartbeat.yml file, but after restarting heartbeat service, service working 2-3 secand and then sending me this output message

> Ping remote services for availability and log results to Elasticsearch or send to Logstash

I deleted my added line `setup.dashboards.enabled: true` and have not get that messages, hearthbeats worked, sent all beats to ELK server, but didn't send monitor's index

[image]

Can anybody help my to solve this issue

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit further? `setup.dashboards.enabled` specifies that the sample dashboards be loaded into Kibana. Do you have a problem with that? On the index side, the default index would be 'heartbeat-date' or 'heartbeat-version-date'. I can see that in your index pattern, so is there a problem there?

Comment: I'm trying to load dashboard where I can check my servers state (up,down), configured my Heartbeat to send metrics  to Logstash, then I was learn about dashboard specific for heartbeat, where I can see my services status(up and down). So added an ssh.yml in the monitors.d directory , after that run my heartbeat, all worked but I have not seen heartbeat index in kibana, soI tried to add `setup.dashboards.enabled: true` line in heartbeat.yml, heartbeat worked 3 sec, and turned down, with this message 

Ping remote services for availability and log results to Elasticsearch or send to Logstash